# How to change of the text color of checked TreeNodes in Treeview in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, treeview

I have created a Tree View in my Asp.net page.Now user may checked the check box in the TreeView.So, now i want to change the text color of the tree node for highlighting the user selected nodes.

Please Guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bctbxtcb%28v=vs.80%29) for the solution.

In short, you should try something like

```
TreeNode node;
// Define the node here.
if (node.Checked == true)
    node.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
// Then use TreeView.Refresh() method to redraw your TreeView
```

Comment: :There is no such attribute called ForeColor in TreeView Web Control.But it is in Windows Form Application.